# Styling button background-image, button icon image, and text using CSS sprites

Tags: css, hover, button, css-sprites

I'm trying to elegantly solve a styling issue with some buttons and images. My goal is to have buttons that look like the following:

*(Hacky mspaint mockup)*

[image: Button Example]
<sub>(source: [robhruska.com](http://www.robhruska.com/images/button-example.png))</sub>

However, I have a set of criteria I'd like to meet:

- I also need to be able to have the icon image exist as a button alone, with no text (i.e. the button background is the icon image and the button width/height = icon image width/height).
- The icon-only button needs to support `:hover` states that change the background icon.
- The text buttons need to support the gradient background changing on `:hover`, but the icon itself does not have to change.

I have both the icon image and gradient image available to me in a vertical CSS sprite image.

Currently, I can only think to do this with separate sets of styles for the text buttons and icon-only buttons, along the lines of:

```
<!-- text-button -->
<!--   button.text-button would have gradient background and border -->
<!--   button.text-button:hover would change to the hover gradient -->
<!--   .icon would have the icon background (icon border is included in image) -->
<button class="text-button">
    <div class="icon-delete">Button Text</div>
</button>

<!-- icon-only button -->
<!--   button.icon-button would have the specific icon image background -->
<!--   button.icon-button:hover would change to the hover state background -->
<!--   button styling is different than .text-button, since icon border is included in image -->
<button class="icon-button-delete"></button>
```

I don't particularly like using the inner `<div>` for the text button, since it seems to add more markup that might be unnecessary. It also makes it so that if I wanted to go back later and add text to a button, I'd have to change several components instead of just changing the button class. It also means that I probably have to define the image positions for my icon sprites for several different combinations of button/div styles, which isn't DRY.

To summarize my question: How can I do this with a **single top-level style** on the `<button>`, rather than using nested elements or separate styles for the icon- vs text- buttons? It doesn't necessarily have to be a `<button>` either, it could be any element if it accomplishes this elegantly.

I don't really need a full code sample, just a suggestion for how it might be accomplished best.

Comment: It seems as though this might not be possible to do easily. A simple solution is to just get rid of the gradient and use a solid background color.

Comment: Additionally, this looks possible with CSS3 and multiple background support.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the markup a bit:

```
<div class="button">
    <a class="yourIcon">Button Text</a>
</div>
```

.button gets the gradient image.

.yourIcon can then get an icon for a background if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just use an `<img>` with a transparent gif and a CSS background-image instead of your icon div. And a span for the text. For the text-free version of the button, just leave out the span and adjust the button class.

I've built a crude demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/TTyPZ/3/

Version 2: http://jsfiddle.net/z9pD9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 for taking the time to provide the code sample. This is definitely an alternative that will work, although it doesn't necessarily address my plea of a 'single, top-level style'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simplify it at max: just use gradient as background and insert insert another tag with icon as background inside, use css vertical-align property (it accepts % values) to place the icon properly aligned to text.

instead of using div tags consider using `<b>` tag, ir saves ytou some bytes and it is s google technique by the way.

hope this helps

Comment: I'm not quite following you here - what you're suggesting seems to be similar to what I gave in my example, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create 2 separate button elements and use absolute positioning to get the icon button on top of the big button?